# Configure a Lambda Warmer using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

It's possible to configure a Lambda warmer function using AWS SAM.

```
Resources:
  # ...
  Web:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: web/
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      FunctionName: !Sub myproject-${Stage}-web
      Events:
        Root:
          Type: Api # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref WebRestApi
        RootProxy:
          Type: Api # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref WebRestApi
        WarmingSchedule:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(5 minutes)
            Input: '{ "warmer":true,"concurrency":3 }'
      MemorySize: 512
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaRole
```

How would one create a warmer using the AWS CDK? Is there an "out of the box" solution or would a custom lambda function using `Schedule.cron` be necessary?

Comment: Warming a lambda function is an anti-pattern and now really unnecessary with the improved networking for vpc enabled functions. I'm assuming you want to do this because of the eni creation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a cron job in Cloudwatch which triggers your lambda to keep it warm
or you use the serverless plugin:

https://serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm/